# Force msbuild to build a project which is unselected in solution config

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, cmake

I use msbuild at command line to build a generated solution file:

```
msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=Win32 build\zlib\vc-9.0\x86\zlib.sln
```

The problem is that the solution generated by cmake has a project INSTALL which is not built by default.

```
minigzip:
  Die Datei "c:\Library\build\zlib\vc-9.0\x86\minigzip.tmp_Release_Win32.vcproj
  " wird gelöscht.
ALL_BUILD:
  Die Datei "c:\Library\build\zlib\vc-9.0\x86\ALL_BUILD.tmp_Release_Win32.vcpro
  j" wird gelöscht.
INSTALL:
  The project "INSTALL" is not selected for building in solution configuration
  "Release|Win32".
Done Building Project "c:\Library\build\zlib\vc-9.0\x86\zlib.sln" (default targ
ets).


Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

How can I force the target INSTALL to be build without manually open the soultion and set the checkbox for the config?

One solution is to call the vcproj file directly (as I did here)

```
msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=Win32 build\zlib\vc-9.0\x86\INSTALL.vcproj
```

but this prints the warning

```
Microsoft (R)-Buildmodul, Version 3.5.30729.6387
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.6400]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Build started 06.07.2013 17:07:57.
Project "c:\Library\build\zlib\vc-9.0\x86\INSTALL.vcproj" on node 0 (default ta
rgets).
c:\Library\build\zlib\vc-9.0\x86\INSTALL.vcproj : warning MSB4098: MSBuild is i
nvoking VCBuild to build this project. Project-to-project references between VC
++ projects (.VCPROJ) and C#/VB/VJ# projects (.CSPROJ, .VBPROJ, .VJSPROJ) are n
ot supported by the command-line build systems when building stand-alone VC++ p
rojects. Projects that contain such project-to-project references will fail to
build. Please build the solution file containing this project instead.
Done Building Project "c:\Library\build\zlib\vc-9.0\x86\INSTALL.vcproj" (defaul
t targets).


Build succeeded.
```

As you can see, the build succeeded. I'm able to ensure the correct build by calling the solution first, but I want to **force the solution** to build the project INSTALL, too.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is impossible. And the workaround you already found seems good enough no? As an alternative can't you use something like "cmake --build --target install"? It's been a while since I used cmake but I seem to remember you can have it invoke msbuild etc for you instead of doing it manually.

Comment: thanks a lot, post this as answer and I'll accept this as valid solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. Looking at msbuild's command line options and in the solution file, there's nothing to support it. But since you're using cmake, you can use it to to build everything for you without having to do it manually. I found [this thread](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-November/040530.html) which basically asks the same question as you, and has the correct syntax using the idea already I put it the comment:

```
cmake --build . --target install
```

Looking somewhat further, from the `devenv` cmmand line options it seems it does have the functionality you're after. This forces a build of the given project even if it's not enabled in the Configuration Manager:

```
devenv build\zlib\vc-9.0\x86\zlib.sln /Build Release /project INSTALL
```

Comment: if you want cmake to build in release mode, you may want to use: "cmake --build . --target install --config Release"

Answer (score 5):

[stijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17504961/417197) is the "idiomatic" way of building targets through cmake.

Note however that MSbuild can build both solution files **and** project files. Instead of calling `msbuild zlib.sln`, you could also call `msbuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj`.

Similarly, you can call `msbuild INSTALL.vcxproj`.

Comment: I already did (see my posted code). But this throws warnings.

Comment: @Beachwalker. Apologies... It should work with VS2010 or later. I didn't notice that you were building "pre-VS2008" vcproj files...

Comment: Thanks, worked for me in VS2017 even for an installer project that has a dependency on other projects in the main solution

Answer (score 3):

Using the solution generated by CMake version 3.2.2, it is indeed not possible to build the INSTALL target from msbuild through the solution. The root cause is that for the INSTALL target, the solution only contains entries like those in the section GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms):

```
    {11C4D30A-3B6A-4350-BD7D-B343F3A843C0}.Debug|Win32.ActiveCfg = Debug|Win32
```

If you add entries like these:

```
    {11C4D30A-3B6A-4350-BD7D-B343F3A843C0}.Debug|Win32.Build.0 = Debug|Win32
```

Then it becomes possible to build the INSTALL target with a command like this:

```
    msbuild <pathToProject>.sln /target:INSTALL
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to build the project directly, but don't forget to specify Configuration and platform.

`msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=Win32 INSTALL.vcxproj`